# Why li elements are overlapping with `block` display?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a responsive menu as follows.

```css
.menu {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.menu li {
  display: inline;
}
.menu li a {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}
.menu li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #ddd;
}
@media (max-width: 620px) {
  .menu li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#/home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#/experience">Experience</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#/education">Education</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#/opensource">Open Source</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#/contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But the menu entries are overlapping in small screens. Why this problem is happening? Also, I have set width to 100%, but entries does not change size in small screens as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `display:inline-block` for the anchor tag

```
.menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
.menu {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.menu li {
  display: inline;
}
.menu li a {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #ddd;
}
@media (max-width: 620px) {
  .menu li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#/home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#/experience">Experience</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#/education">Education</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#/opensource">Open Source</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#/contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah. That solves the first problem of overlapping. I also want to make menu width to 100%. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menu {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.menu li {
  display: inline;
}
.menu li a {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
  display:block;
}
.menu li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #ddd;
}
@media (max-width: 620px) {
  .menu li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#/home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#/experience">Experience</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#/education">Education</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#/opensource">Open Source</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#/contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

anchor by default has `display: inline` property. you need to set it to `display:block` if you need full-width or set it to `display:inline-block` to take the size as per the text.